# Confused by Python returning JSON as string instead of literal

Tags: python, json, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've done some coding in RoR, and in Rails, when I return a JSON object via an API call, it returns as

`{ "id" : "1", "name" : "Dan" }`.

However in Python (with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy), when I return a JSON object via json.dumps or jsonpickle.encode it is returned as

`"{ \"id\" : \"1\", \"name\": \"Dan\" }"` which seems very unwieldily as it can't easily be parsed on the other end (by an iOS app in this case - Obj-C).

What am I missing here, and what should I do to return it as a JSON literal, rather than a JSON string?

This is what my code looks like:

```
people = models.UserRelationships.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id, active=ACTIVE_RECORD)
friends = people.filter_by(friends=YES)

json_object = jsonpickle.encode(friends.first().as_dict(), unpicklable=False, keys=True)
print(json_object)  # this prints here, i.e. { "id" : "1", "name" : "Dan" }

return json_object # this returns "{ \"id\" : \"1\", \"name\": \"Dan\" }" to the browser
```

Comment: json.dumps will return a string representation of the object. See help(json.dumps) -> Serialize `obj` to a JSON formatted `str`.

Comment: If you want JSON, you should use the relevant modules to serialize as JSON. Printing something does not turn it into JSON.

Comment: A JSON literal *is* a string. JSON is a *notation*. JSON can only ever be a sequence of characters. You're confusing a data structure with its representation.

Comment: The code you're showing can't possibly do what you're claiming. `json_object = print(json_object)` will set `json_object` to `None`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I wrote the code too quickly! Sorry. I've edited it above. The issue is when I return it to the browswer, not when I print it.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX What i'm confused about is that in Rails when I return the json sequence of characters to the browser it isn't wrapped in quotes or escaped, yet in python using my code above when I return the json sequence of characters to the browser it is wrapped in quotes with all the double quotes escaped. How can I an unquoted, not escaped sequence of characters to the browser in python, that is easy for the downstream client (an iOS app) to parse?

Comment: First of all, the code above obviously isn't what you're using and can't lead to the error you're describing. Please, show us the real code. Second, if you're using Flask, you should be using flask.jsonify for the JSON response.

Comment: @PedroWerneck, that is the code actually. Anyway your suggestion to use flask.jsonify is returning an object with a mimetype of JSON which is what I'm after. I think the trick was understanding the difference between a http response and a JSON str which are two separate things, and I'm after the http response. If you want to post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @Dan Posted. In Flask, if you return a string from a view, if will be wrapped into a response with a text/html content-type header and a 200 status code. jsonify takes the object, encodes to json, and wraps it in a response with an application/json header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `flask.jsonify`, which will not only encode correctly, but also set the `content-type` headers accordingly.

```
people = models.UserRelationships.query.filter_by(user_id=user_id, active=ACTIVE_RECORD)
friends = people.filter_by(friends=YES)

return jsonify(friends.first().as_dict())
```

Comment: Thanks! My issue was failing to understand the difference between a http response and a JSON string. I'm after the http response when using it for an API.

Answer (score 5):

What is missing in your understanding here is that when you use the JSON modules in Python, you're not working with a JSON object. JSON is by definition just a string that matches a certain standard.

Lets say you have the string:

```
friends = '{"name": "Fred", "id": 1}'
```

If you want to work with this data in python, you will want to load it into a python object:

```
import json
friends_obj = json.loads(friends)
```

At this point friends_obj is a python dictionary.

If you want to convert it (or any other python dictionary or list) then this is where json.dumps comes in handy:

```
friends_str = json.dumps(friends_obj)
print friends_str
'{"name": "Fred", "id": 1}'
```

However if we attempt to "dump" the original friends string you'll see you get a different result:

```
dumped_str = json.dumps(friends)
print dumped_str
'"{\\"name\\": \\"Fred\\", \\"id\\": 1}"'
```

This is because you're basically attempting to encode an ordinary string as JSON and it is escaping the characters. I hope this helps make sense of things!

Cheers

Comment: Thanks, the issue isn't with the printing though. When printed it is okay, its when I return it to the browser that it is double encoded. i.e. `return json_object # this returns "{ \"id\" : \"1\", \"name\": \"Dan\" }"` to the browser

Comment: Printing just shows what would have been returned to the browser. Whatever you're using to return the data is doing encoding for you.

Answer (score 3):

This is almost always a sign that you're double-encoding your data somewhere. For example:

```
>>> obj = { "id" : "1", "name" : "Dan" }
>>> j = json.dumps(obj)
>>> jj = json.dumps(j)
>>> print(obj)
{'id': '1', 'name': 'Dan'}
>>> print(j)
{"id": "1", "name": "Dan"}
>>> print(jj)
"{\"id\": \"1\", \"name\": \"Dan\"}"
```

Here, `jj` is a perfectly valid JSON string representation—but it's not a representation of `obj`, it's a representation of the string `j`, which is useless.

Normally you don't do this directly; instead, either you started with a JSON string rather than an object in the first place (e.g., you got it from a client request or from a text file), or you called some function in a library like `requests` or `jsonpickle` that implicitly calls `json.dumps` with an already-encoded string. But either way, it's the same problem, with the same solution: Just don't double-encode.

Comment: I'm using jsonpickle.encode on a Flask-SQLAlchemy row that's converted to a dict (i.e. `jsonpickle.encode(friends.first().as_dict(), unpicklable=False, keys=True)`) so it's probably not already an encoded string unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Dan: What are you returning this from? How is your app configured? If Flask is expecting you to give it an object that it will encode, and you're encoding an object and giving it the resulting string, it will end up double-encoded.

Comment: @Dan: As a side note, why are you using `jsonpickle` instead of the stdlib `json` module, or Flask's builtin `jsonify`? The whole point of `jsonpickle` is that it gives you a way to wrap and unwrap Python types (like custom classes) that don't map directly to JSON, which is useless unless the other side is also using `jsonpickle`, which a web browser or ObjC app is obviously not.

Comment: You're right. That's been my issue :/ I should've been using jsonify.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using Django here, in which case do something like

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
...
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(friends.first().as_dict()))
```

Comment: I'm not using Django, so I guess I can't use HttpResponse? I'm using Python, Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy..

Comment: Ah, sorry, I jumped to conclusions; some of the syntax looks like Django but isn't. Django is modular, so you can use bits of if you like, but if you're using Flask you probably don't need to.